# Hbase splitting for small table

Tags: hbase, bigdata

For a small table (less than 1 million rows and around 1 or 2GB) that will be accessed by a lot of jobs in parallel (insertions and range scan), what is the best way to create this table in terms of splitting ?

The goal is to have good performance and low latency on requests.

Max size of regions in my cluster is 20GB and there are 20 nodes with regionservers.

Thanks.

Edit:

- Table accessed by Spark jobs (and manually by Hbase shell / Phoenix)
- Row Key on 2 columns (tablename & datetime)
- One insertion by day + rangescan

Comment: You haven't provided enough details for a decent answer - please elaborate more about the table access patterns. This is crucial for getting the best out of hbase.

Comment: what kind of data is going into table, specify the row key here. that should help people to suggest

Comment: Informations I know have been added.